# How are mines triggered in Captain Sonar?

Tags: captain-sonar

For all normal system activations, the real-time game is put on hold:

> To activate a system...announce "STOP" and raise a fist. All other players stop what they are doing and listen.

This seems important for multiple reasons, including making sure the game is in a single consistent state during the resolution of the activation.

However, the rules also seem to treat *triggering* a mine differently from activating a system:

> At any time, except while surfaced, the Captain can trigger a mine by raising a fist, announcing "TRIGGERING A MINE"

So: **does triggering a mine count as a system activation?**

If yes, does that mean that you have to charge the system once to drop and then charge it again to trigger, and that the engineer must have weapons systems online for both drop and trigger? Or if no, does that mean that the game *isn't* on hold while the trigger is resolved, even though the game *is* on hold while the very similar torpedo explosion is resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You must STOP in order to trigger a mine, and the Engine Room can't have a breakdown for the *MINE + TORPEDO* system.**

[This thread](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1630118/designer-answer-system-usage-and-mine-detonation-q) over on BGG relays information from the designers. In order to detonate a mine, the Engineer needs weapon systems online:

> And to detonate a mine you also need to have ALL the red "lights" clear in the Engine room

The last line also clarifies that a STOP needs to occur during detonation:

> With these answers, I think a good way to describe the rules is that each team is only allowed 1 STOP (either system activation or mine detonation) between movements.

Comment: Interesting - the 1 STOP between movements is totally absent from the English rules. Apparently they're working on a better translation...

Comment: @BenjaminCosman Yeah. That's how I understand the situation as well. I'll be interested to see if any updated rules make it online.

Comment: @BenjaminCosman The rulebook appears to have been updated. I've just got the game and there's a bold yellow note about no two STOPs in a row.